# How does a MQTT-Broker handle topics

Tags: mqtt

in concern of performance i'm asking myself how MQTT-broker react to different hierarchies.
Let's say you got  customers in your database with several attributes represented in your mqtt paths. Would it be more effective like this:

customer1/order 
customer1/name 
customer1/adress 
customer2/order 
customer2/name 
customer2/adress

or like this:

order/customer1/ 
order/customer2/ 
name/customer1/ 
name/customer2/ 
adress/customer1/ 
adress/customer2/

I can see the point, that you've got more subtopics, if you start with a static identifier (like an attribute) followed by the variable part. Does it affect the performance the way the topics are structured? If not, are there any best practices? 
Regards.

Comment: what are you trying to observe with the arch.??? can you have an Order without costumers?? or can you have a costumer without orders??

Comment: In fact i want to know if it does affect the performance and if not, if there is a best practice to structure topics clearly (especially for other developers).

Comment: This will entirely depend on how a particular broker is implemented

Answer (score 1):

At a MQTT protocol level the topic structure will have no impact on performance (apart from the fact a longer topic will mean a larger message header)

The only place it may have an impact would be in the matcher in the broker to determine which subscribers should receive the message, but as I said in the comments this will be entirely down to how the broker has implemented it's matching algorithm